# Permit few requests without authentication, and authenticate remaining all request

Tags: java, spring, authentication, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I have configured my resource server with below http configuration. Basically I want to set configuration like permit few requests without authentication and all other request which I have not specified should be allowed only if the user has valid access token.

Note that I am using spring security oauth2 and spring boot.

```
@Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http
        .exceptionHandling()
        .and()
        .csrf()
        .requireCsrfProtectionMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/oauth/authorize"))
        .disable()
        .headers()
        .frameOptions().disable().disable()
        .sessionManagement()
        .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
        .and()
          .antMatcher("**")
          .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/hello/")
            .permitAll()
          .anyRequest()
            .authenticated();
    }
```

When I try to access `http://localhost:8889/hello`, It gives me below 401 UnAuthorized response even though I have configured it with permitAll

```
{
    "error": "unauthorized",
    "error_description": "An Authentication object was not found in the SecurityContext"
}
```

On the contrary I checked with below configuration

```
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/hello/").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/hello2/").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/secure/**").authenticated()
        .antMatchers("/secure2/**").authenticated();
```

It worked well like hello an hello2 are allowed without token and, secure and secure2 gives error response if token is not passed or invalid token is passed.

Can someone please tell me what I am missing?

Comment: The problem is the antmatcher ending with a slash while you are not accessing it like that.

Comment: I tired "http://localhost:8889/hello/" , but facing same error. I also tried by changing to  .antMatchers("/hello") and accessing "http://localhost:8889/hello" but again same error.